# How to do union all with different order by conditions

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, union-all

I have a table with data like 
[image]

I want all the records from the table but which the record having EnquiryStatus=1 and order by LastAttendendedDate should come on the top and remaining records should come after those records. I tried to select twice with where condition and tried to union all them, But with that union all not allowing me to order by on different ways. I can do it in c# by retriving the data as two table and merge them as single. But I want it in sql..

EDITS:

I want something like

```
Select * From EnquiryMaster A Where  A.BranchID=16 and EnquiryStatus=1  ORDER BY A.CreatedDate Desc     
UNION ALL
Select * From EnquiryMaster A Where  A.BranchID=16 and EnquiryStatus in(0,2,3) ORDER BY EnquiryStatus,A.CreatedDate Desc
```

Comment: Don't post images, links will die and the sample data is difficult to copy/paste. It would be helpful if you'd provide a [sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with this data instead. To create it you can use the "Text-To-DDL" functionality there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from your_table
order by case when EnquiryStatus=1 then LastAttendendedDate end DESC
```

Comment: I want exactly like this but with order by desc

Comment: getting error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'desc'.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ORDER BY CASE WHEN EnquiryStatus='1' THEN LastAttendendedDate END DESC
```

You can use this in sql.

Comment: I want all the records not only with 1